# How to host two websites 1st on domain root and 2nd on sub-directory

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have two websites, web-1 and web-2.

web1 is a HTML website and it's on the root domain which is domain.com
web-2 is a PHP app and it's on a sub-directory which is domain.com/web-2

web-1 is working normal but web-2 is not loading the website in full.

Here is my .htaccess file located in web-2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# option to force redirect to ssl (https) - uncomment the two lines below
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on    
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.svg|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.png|\.ttf|\.woff)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: _"but web-2 is not loading the website in full"_ - Please explain more what that _actually_ means. Also check your browsers developer tools to see if you get any load errors.

Comment: You likely want to configure [Apache vhosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: Are you using Nginx or Apache for hosting?

Comment: I'm using Apache2